# How to use mysqltuner from remote host

Tags: mysql, mysqltuner

We do not have access to our servers with operating system console. Our production environment is Ubuntu 12.
Is it possible to use mysqltuner from remote host?
If yes, please provide guidelines. We are using mysql5.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I am about to show you comes from lines 89-122 of the [mysqltuner.pl code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl):

You will still have to connect like a mysql client:

```
Connection and Authentication
    --host <hostname>    Connect to a remote host to perform tests (default: localhost)
    --socket <socket>    Use a different socket for a local connection
    --port <port>        Port to use for connection (default: 3306)
    --user <username>    Username to use for authentication
    --pass <password>    Password to use for authentication
```

Since you are using a remote host, use parameters to supply values from the OS

```
--forcemem <size>    Amount of RAM installed in megabytes
--forceswap <size>   Amount of swap memory configured in megabytes
```

You may have to contact your remote SysAdmin to ask how much RAM and swap you have

If the database has too many tables, or very large table, use this:

```
--skipsize           Don't enumerate tables and their types/sizes (default: on)
                     (Recommended for servers with many tables)
```